# How to get results from an Adobe Captivate 5.5 quiz (using javascript - or anything really)

Tags: adobe-captivate

Googling this topic gives me this:

http://blogs.adobe.com/captivate/2010/08/reporting-the-quiz-results-to-a-local-server.html

Which

a) doesn't work at all (SWF just doesn't post to the page - no error message or other hints), and...

b) Relies on the user clicking "post result" after the test, and...

c) Pops up a little window asking them who they are (enabling very easy cheating - their friends can just hit the button again and enter their own details to "pass").

Other google results include:

- Solutions for old versions of Captivate that don't work with the current one (5.x)
- Solutions that don't write to a database/xml/variable (and can't easily be made to, e.g.: it sends an email for every result set)
- Solutions that seem significantly more complex than just writing my own simple Captivate-like app from scratch (which all seem to have one of the aforementioned problems too).

Has anyone found or worked out how to do this? I just need to get the results out into a format my app can read - javascript variable, DOM object, xml fragment, database, querystring parameter, anything.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to your question?

Comment: A colleague eventually had limited success with it, talking to captivate with javascript as if it was a SCORM compliant LCMS, but the result was incredibly kludgy, and had serious issues that nullified the whole point of the process. On top of that, it took forever to create. Much easier and more effective to write our own software to do what we wanted captivate to do, so we did that instead.

Answer (score 0):

An old topic, but [here](http://wheatblog.com/2010/01/cp2db-adobe-captivate-quiz-reporting-with-phpmysql-version-2/) you will find the answer, I personally use this method to store results from **Adobe Captivate 5.5 into MySQL** database (you may need to adjust the provided scripts according your needs).

This method however will not work on newest version of Adobe Captivate, unfortunatelly.